# cuboid with $z=0$ and $z=y$

Tags: vector-analysis

Compute $\int \int _S F \cdot n \hspace{2mm} dS$ where $$F(x,y,z)=(x-z\cos y, y-x^2+x\sin z+z^3, x+y+z)$$ and $r$ is the surface that bounds the solid between the planes $$x=0,\hspace{2mm}x=1,\hspace{2mm}y=0,\hspace{2mm}y=2,\hspace{2mm}z=0, \hspace{2mm} z=y$$

Are there typos in this? What is $r$? And I found it kind of weird that z=y. The divF=3 so do we just do (using divergence theorem) $$3\int \limits_{x=0}^1   \int \limits_{y=0}^2 \int \limits_{z=0}^y dzdydx$$ which gives $6$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right!

I wrote
$$F = (x - zcos(y),y - {x^2} + xsin(z) + {z^3},x + y + z)$$
as a 2-form:
$$\omega  = (x - cos(y)z)dy \wedge dz + (y - {x^2} + xsin(z) + {z^3})dz \wedge dx + (x + y + z)dx \wedge dy$$

calculate exterior derivative:

$$\begin{gathered}
  d\omega  = dx \wedge dy \wedge dz + dy \wedge dz \wedge dx + dz \wedge dx \wedge dy \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
  d\omega  = 3\cdot dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

applied Stoke's theorem and got:

$$\begin{gathered}
  \int\limits_S \omega   = \int\limits_V {d\omega }  = \int\limits_V {3\cdot dx \wedge dy \wedge dz}  = 3 \cdot \int\limits_V {dx \wedge dy \wedge dz}  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = 3 \cdot \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^2 {\int\limits_0^y {dz} } }  \cdot dy \cdot dx = 3 \cdot \int\limits_0^1 {\int\limits_0^2 {y\cdot dy \cdot dx} }  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = 3 \cdot \int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{2^2}}}{2}\cdot dx}  = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot \int\limits_0^1 {dx}  = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 6 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

the same!

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct. I suspect that $r$ was supposed to be $S$. There's nothing strange about having $z = y$ as one of the bounds -- it's a plane that makes a $45^{\circ}$ angle relative to the $xy$-plane.